# take table from top of new pages

Tags: tables

I take a template but I don't like see the table top of my new pages I just wanna see it on the first page. This is the template I used :
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ist-ul-lab-guide/jmzhxftbbgwk

Is there anybody to know what should I do?